# Dropdown login form wont work in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css

So i've got a login screen setup after following some tutorials and guides online. I've put the code in a jsfiddle : [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n35me6on/). Now i cant get the code to work. I'm quite new to Jquery so it might be a rookie mistake. The problem im having is that when you click login the menu is supposed to drop down and show the login form. Any help or suggestions are welcome and i thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#login-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');          

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
      else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
    })
});
```

---

Image of my functions.php:

[image]

Comment: updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n35me6on/1/

Comment: I see you enabled jquery. I shall double-check if my website has that enabled or not.

Comment: wordpress by default add jquery core file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress, you need to write jquery code like

```
function head_script() {?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
  $('#login-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');          

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
      else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
    });
})(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php 
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'head_script' );
```

Comment: Do i need to wrap it in script tags? adding your code instead of my own crashed the website.

Comment: Keeps crashing the website. So i've got the html simply in my wp-header and the css in the style.css file. Thats all fine. I'm adding this code to my functions.php is that what i might be doing wrong? I can add a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: Added a screenshot of my functions.php

Comment: It keeps crashing my code. Do i need to place it in the functions.php at all? If i add a .js file to my site and put the code in there wouldnt that work better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65070/discussion-between-bhumi-shah-and-marco-geertsma).